# Grails CXF web service including all methods in WSDL

Tags: web-services, grails, cxf

I am try to implement a SOAP web service in Grails using the CXF plugin. My service class is very simple.

```
package com.ld.api

import com.ld.domain.*
import javax.jws.*
import grails.converters.XML


class CabinetService {


    static transactional = true
    static expose=['cxf']
    String getCabinetList() {

        String list = Cabinet.list()

        //return list as XML

        return "jim"

    }


    def serviceMethod() {
        println "IN serviceMethod"
        "Hello...."
    }


}
```

and I'm getting this WSDL:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="CabinetService" targetNamespace="http://api.ld.com/"><wsdl:types><xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://api.ld.com/"><xsd:element name="serviceMethod" type="tns:serviceMethod"/><xsd:complexType name="serviceMethod"><xsd:sequence/></xsd:complexType><xsd:element name="serviceMethodResponse" type="tns:serviceMethodResponse"/><xsd:complexType name="serviceMethodResponse"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xsd:anyType"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:schema></wsdl:types><wsdl:message name="serviceMethodResponse"><wsdl:part element="tns:serviceMethodResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:message name="serviceMethod"><wsdl:part element="tns:serviceMethod" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part></wsdl:message><wsdl:portType name="CabinetServicePortType"><wsdl:operation name="serviceMethod"><wsdl:input message="tns:serviceMethod" name="serviceMethod">
    </wsdl:input><wsdl:output message="tns:serviceMethodResponse" name="serviceMethodResponse">
    </wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:portType><wsdl:binding name="CabinetServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:CabinetServicePortType"><soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/><wsdl:operation name="serviceMethod"><soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/><wsdl:input name="serviceMethod"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:input><wsdl:output name="serviceMethodResponse"><soap:body use="literal"/></wsdl:output></wsdl:operation></wsdl:binding><wsdl:service name="CabinetService"><wsdl:port binding="tns:CabinetServiceSoapBinding" name="CabinetServicePort"><soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/LucanDOCS2013/services/cabinet"/></wsdl:port></wsdl:service></wsdl:definitions>
```

The automatically gennerated "serviceMethod" is included in the WSDL, but getCabinetList() is not included. I have tried various combinations of annotations, but have had no luck.

I'm on grails 2.0.3 and version 0.9.0 of the plugin. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only methods defined with "def" are visible in the WSDL, you're missing it by getCabinetList()

Also use: static expose = [ 'cxfjax' ] ... see the latest plugin docs.

I am also using this in my exported methods:

```
@WebMethod( operationName="createUpdateUser" )
@WebResult( name="result" )
def ResultDTO createUpdateUser( @WebParam( name="authorizationCode" ) String a uthorizationCode,
                                @WebParam( name="username" ) String username ) ) { ... }
```

Also don't forgett to annotate the classes, you're transporting via the service, or you end up with WSDL without parameters and data types:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ResultDTO {
    int code;
    String message;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. I was apparently using documentation of the older plugin. You suggestions work perfectly.